# How to get path to WebContent/WEB-INF/classes directory

Tags: java, file, path

I have the following code:

```
final String MY_DIR_PATH = "myDir/";
URL destDirUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(MY_DIR_PATH);
if (destDirUrl == null) {
    // what should go here?
}
Path destDirPath = Paths.get(destDirUrl.toURI());
if (Files.notExists(destDirPath)) {
    LOGGER.info("New directory \"" + destDirPath + "\" will be created.");
    Files.createDirectories(destDirPath);
}
```

If `myDir` exists, then on debugging the `desDirUrl` in second line above contains:

```
file:/D:/myDevelopment/MyProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/myDir/
```

However, now I have to enhance this to handle the case that if `myDir` doesn't exist, then create `myDir` in `file:/D:/myDevelopment/MyProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/` path.

I don't know what to put inside the `if` so that I get the same `URL` for the next line to get `destDirPath`.

I tried,

```
URL classURL = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

But that returns `URL` as:

```
file:/D:/myDevelopment/MyProject/java/bin/
```

which is incorrect.

How do I:

1) Retrieve `file:/D:/myDevelopment/MyProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes` as `URL` first.

2) How can I then add `/myDir` to that so that next line `Path destDirPath = Paths.get(destDirUrl.toURI());` works as before.

Update:

I also tried:

```
URL classURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".");
```

and

```
URL classURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/");
```

and

```
 URL classURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("");
```

but none are working.

Comment: Are you going to run your app as an exploded one or as a single `.war` archive?

Comment: @KenBekov: As exploded one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
    URL url = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    try {
        URI uri = new URI(url.toString() + "/myDir");
        Path path  = Paths.get(uri);
        if(!Files.exists(path)){
            Files.createDirectory(path);
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```